# How to Change All Sql Columns of One DataType into Another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, performance, types

I have a database (`Sql Server 2005`) where there are dozens of `tables`, each of which has a number of `columns` (on average 10-20) with datatype set to `nvarchar(max)`. This is absolutely killing performance (some of these columns are being used for `joins` and some of the tables have 100K+ rows). I would like to change all of these columns to be `varchar(250)`. What would be the best way to automate this? (I could use `Management Studio`, or I could create a utility to perform this through an `ASP.net` website that has access to the db, whichever is easier).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a working script that uses `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to find all of the `*varchar(max)` columns and converts them to `varchar(255)`:

```
declare @schema nvarchar(255)
declare @table nvarchar(255)
declare @col nvarchar(255)
declare @dtype nvarchar(255)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

declare maxcols cursor for
select
    c.TABLE_SCHEMA,
    c.TABLE_NAME,
    c.COLUMN_NAME,
    c.DATA_TYPE
from
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t on
    c.TABLE_CATALOG = t.TABLE_CATALOG
    and c.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA
    and c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
    and t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
where
    c.DATA_TYPE like '%varchar'
    and c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1

open maxcols

fetch next from maxcols into @schema, @table, @col, @dtype

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    set @sql = 'alter table [' + @schema + '].[' + @table + 
        '] alter column [' + @col + '] ' + @dtype + '(255)'
    exec sp_executesql @sql

    fetch next from maxcols into @schema, @table, @col, @dtype
end

close maxcols
deallocate maxcols
```

This is about the only use of cursors that I ever condone, but it's a good one. Essentially, it finds all of the `*varchar(max)`, builds the `alter` statement, and then executes it using `sp_executesql`.

Enjoy!

Comment: This doesn't work perfectly since it also brings in columns from views

Comment: Now, how to drop constraints and put them back while doing this, since we cannot alter cols with a constraint in place?

Comment: How about including a check to only apply to columns with max length < 255 so that no data is potentially truncated?

Answer (score 3):

You can easily find them, using:

```
select 'alter table ' + quotename(o.name) + ' alter column ' + quotename(c.name) + ' varchar(250); '
from sys.columns c
  join
  sys.objects o
  on o.object_id = c.object_id
where o.type = 'U'
and c.user_type_id = 231
and c.max_length = -1
```

So now just grab the results of your query and run it.

Rob

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning... if you put declare @qry nvarchar(max), and select @qry = (.... for xml path('')); exec sp_executesql @qry; --You can do it all in one step. The .... is the current query I have. But then you can't 'sanity check' it so well.

Comment: Do you need to take the column nullability into account? Will this alter columns to be nullable because it doesn't specify either way?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this task is to generate script for the current database and then replace nvarchar(max) with varchar(250) on the text file, and then create the new database.
after that use the Import/export utilities to transfer the data to the new database.

Comment: This doesn't work - SSIS will return an error message stating that the column metadata doesn't match between the source and destination tables