# How to Change All SQL Columns of money and smallmoney into decimal?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have tried to do it using the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327548/how-to-change-all-sql-columns-of-one-datatype-into-another/) by modifying it to the following, but I'm getting an error on:

```
fetch next from maxcols into @schema, @table, @col, @dtype
```

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 25
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to decimal.

Code:

```
declare @schema nvarchar(255)
declare @table nvarchar(255)
declare @col nvarchar(255)
declare @dtype decimal(19,8)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

declare maxcols cursor for
    select
        c.TABLE_SCHEMA, c.TABLE_NAME,
        c.COLUMN_NAME, c.DATA_TYPE
    from
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
    inner join 
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t on c.TABLE_CATALOG = t.TABLE_CATALOG
                                    and c.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA
                                    and c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
                                    and t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
    where
        c.DATA_TYPE like '%money'

open maxcols

fetch next from maxcols into @schema, @table, @col, @dtype

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    set @sql = 'alter table [' + @schema + '].[' + @table + 
        '] alter column [' + @col + '] ' + @dtype
    exec sp_executesql @sql

    fetch next from maxcols into @schema, @table, @col, @dtype
end

close maxcols
deallocate maxcols
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few changes:

Declare the `@dtype` variable of SYSNAME Type and assign a string of data type you want to use, in your case it would be a string `'decimal(19,8)`. You are declaring a variable of `decimal(19,8)` data type, this is not what you want.

You should really declare all the variable of `SYSNAME` type which will be used to hold SQL Server object names, Schema , Table, column names etc.

Also In your select for cursor you dont need to use the data type, it is being filtered out in the `where` clause for the cursor's select statement. So I have taken out the data type column from the select and from the `Fetch next into` line.

Also use `QUOTENAME()` function to add sqaure brackets around the object names.

```
declare  @table     SYSNAME
      ,  @col       SYSNAME 
      ,  @dtype     SYSNAME = 'decimal(19,8)'  --<-- Declare variable of sysname type
      ,  @sql       NVARCHAR(MAX) 
      ,  @schema    SYSNAME;

    declare maxcols cursor for
    select
        c.TABLE_SCHEMA,
        c.TABLE_NAME,
        c.COLUMN_NAME
    from
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
    inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t on
        c.TABLE_CATALOG = t.TABLE_CATALOG
        and c.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA
        and c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
        and t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
    where
        c.DATA_TYPE like '%money'

    open maxcols

    fetch next from maxcols into @schema, @table, @col

    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
        set @sql = N' alter table ' + QUOTENAME(@schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@table) 
                 + N' alter column ' + QUOTENAME(@col) + ' ' + @dtype

        exec sp_executesql @sql

        fetch next from maxcols into @schema, @table, @col
    end

    close maxcols
    deallocate maxcols
```

Comment: How can I drop default constrains on each column before trying to alter it?