# How do you convert all varchar columns/variables/parameters to nvarchar type in one go?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a database which has nearly 1000 `tables`. All the textual type field is of `varchar` type. It has nearly 1000+ `stored procedures` and `functions` too.
These `procedures` and `functions` got their own `varchar` parameters and `varchar` variables. 
I need to convert every `varchar` type field  to `nvarchar` type in one go in every `table, procedures and functions`.
Of-course I could do it one by one but that would take years to do it manually.

I don't need to change the size. If its `varchar(50)`. I want output like `nvarchar(50)`. No change in size.

Comment: Look into this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327548/how-to-change-all-sql-columns-of-one-datatype-into-another

Comment: thanks I did search for similar question but i didn't find it.

Comment: but does it convert the parameters and variables of procedure too?

Comment: No, Above link solution will not convert parameters and variables of procedure.

Comment: For SPs, you can script them out using SSMS and then search/replace using your favourite text editor. You can re-deploy them afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

> Of-course I could do it one by one but that would take years to do it manually.

This appears to be the answer to your question, as if 'in one go' would take years in a single transaction then this would have to be executed in digestible chunks based on what maintenance windows you have to do this.

- Tables first considering any PK-FK ordering of execution
- Views next unless any views are schemabinding, then you'd have to drop view - alter table - recreate view in that order.
- Then functions and SP's.

OR

If it's possible, get a copy of your database, apply all of your changes, then do a switch between your current prod database and that one.  This assumes you can arrange to make sure all prod data in the current db is in the copy when you do the switch.